# A twist on a classic: Getting the most recent entries for an id then getting the highest number out of that group

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table that I'm accessing via tableau:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| date      | active_count | job_id | stage_id |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 7/27/2020 |            2 |  10001 |        8 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 7/27/2020 |          140 |  10001 |       14 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 7/27/2020 |           20 |  10001 |       21 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 7/27/2020 |            1 |  10001 |       37 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 7/27/2020 |            0 |  10001 |       39 |
```

I want to run a query that selects the most recent rows per job_id and then returns the highest stage_id and corresponding job_id with an active_count > 0.

So I want my result to be:

```
+---------+--------+
| stage   | job_id |
+---------+--------+
| 37      |  10001 |
+---------+--------+
```

I know that I can use this sort of thing to get the most recent entry for the job_id:

```
select
    max(t1.stage_id),
    t1.job_id
from
    table1 as t1
left join table1 as t2
      on t1.job_id = t2.job_id and 
        (t1.date < t2.date or 
           (t1.date = t2.date and 
            t1.job_id < t2.job_id))
where 
    t1.active_count > 0
group by
    t1.job_id
```

but I'm not sure if this is efficient/actually working as intended. Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the wrong tag. If SQL server, please specify the version.

Comment: Sorry, @PrebenHuybrechts. MySQL.

Comment: I think it's best to create the schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and mention the link in your question. That way the community will be able to answer your question quicker.

Comment: As long as you have indexes on job_id, date, and active_count that is probably the best way to do it.   You could try combined index on both job_id and date.

Comment: @BrianC thanks for your comment! I just realized I forgot a very important piece:

I needed an additional WHERE condition - t2.date IS NULL. Query working as it should be now! (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your real criteria is more complex than your example you can just use a MAX() of each value you want.

```
SELECT t1.job_id
     , MAX( t1.stage_id )     AS max_stage_id
     , MAX( t1.active_count ) AS max_active_count
FROM table1      AS t1
WHERE t1.active_count > 0
GROUP BY t1.job_id
;
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind if the active_count turns out to be important in this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran this again and landed on the following code which works as intended:

```
select
    max(t1.stage_id),
    t1.job_id
from
    stage_snapshots as t1
left join stage_snapshots as t2
    on t1.job_id = t2.job_id and 
     (t1.date < t2.date or 
       (t1.date = t2.date and 
        t1.job_id < t2.job_id))
where 
    t1.active_count > 0 and 
    t2.date is null
group by
    t1.job_id
```

This does what it's supposed to but it turns out stage_id is not ordered in the way I thought it was so I'll be going back to the drawing board.